# LibGDX / Box2d - only one rectangle is being rendered by debugrenderer

Tags: for-loop, libgdx, iteration, collision-detection, box2d

I'm revisiting [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) game programming and I am unfortunately having to re-learn stuff I used to know.

I'm currently using Tiled Map Editor to make a very simple Donkey Kong style level. I have around 20 rectangles in total for the level.

I've created a box2d world in my main GameScreen class and have a for loop to get the rectangle objects into the world and debugrenderer.

My problem is that only the bottom (and first) rectangle I drew is showing up. I have checked the scale, also I put a `println()` which tells me the object information has been parsed with all the rectangles info showing correct (ie. the rectangles x,y,w,h values) but as I say, only one rectangle shows up on the debugrenderer.

I've just got back into programming after around 6month break and so I'm hoping i've missed something simple. The same code in my old projects still works fine as I've tested some.

Here is my code, any help is massively appreciated. Thanks

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    Viewport v;

    TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    TiledMap map;
    OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;

    World world;
    Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;
    float mapScale = 10f/140f;

    public GameScreen(){
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        v = new FitViewport(Constants.V_WIDTH, Constants.V_HEIGHT, cam);
        cam.setToOrtho(false, v.getWorldWidth(), v.getWorldHeight());

        mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = mapLoader.load("level1.tmx");
        mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, mapScale);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0,-9.8f), true);
        b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        // box2d local variables
        BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
        Body body;

        // create platform object rectangles
        for (MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(2).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)){
            Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject)object).getRectangle();

            bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
            bdef.position.set(rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2 * mapScale, rect.y + rect.getHeight() / 2 * mapScale);

            body = world.createBody(bdef);

            shape.setAsBox(rect.getWidth() / 2 * mapScale, rect.getHeight() / 2 * mapScale);
            fdef.shape = shape;

            body.createFixture(fdef);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        clearScreen();
        draw();
    }

    public void update(float dt){
        mapRenderer.setView(cam);
    }

    public void clearScreen(){
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void draw(){
        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        mapRenderer.render();
        b2dr.render(world, cam.combined);

        spriteBatch.begin();

        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        v.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        spriteBatch.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting time here. I have fixed this.

It was just that I hadnt applied the scale of the map also to the x,y of the rectangles. So i change one line like so, and now it works:

```
  bdef.position.set(rect.getX() * mapScale + rect.getWidth() / 2 * mapScale, rect.y * mapScale + rect.getHeight() / 2 * mapScale);
```